# Layer imported from geoserver is not displayed using OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, layer

I'm importing layer of deepwatertable (coordinate system 32632) from geoserver to display it using OpenLayers but i cannot find it.
Here is the written code:

```
var urlgeoserver="http://localhost:8082/geoserver/BV_chiba/wms"


var urlcouches="BV_chiba:deepwatertable"


var deepwatertable = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source:new ol.imageWMS({
        url: urlgeoserver,
        params:{"LAYERS": urlcouches, "TILED":"true"},

    }),
    title: "deepwatertable"
});
deepwatertable.setVisible(true);


var listcouches= [deepwatertable];
var map = new ol.map({
target: 'map',
layers:listcouches,
view: new ol.view({
center: ol.proj.transform([0, 0], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:32632'),
zoom:10
})
});
```

Comment: I edit the code it but the same issues is appearing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason why WMS cannot be tiled, it's more efficient as as tiles can be cached, but `ol.layer.Tile` needs to be used with `ol.source.TileWMS`.  If you don't want tiled WMS you must use `ol.layer.Image` with `ol.source.ImageWMS`  `ol.Map` and `ol.View` also need capital letters.  The projection (unless it is EPSG:3857) must be specified in the source and view options, and in a proj4 definition (and registered if using OpenLayers 5), and you will need to include the proj4 library `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js"></script>`

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:32632","+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs");

ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4); // only needed if using OpenLayers 5

var urlgeoserver="http://localhost:8082/geoserver/BV_chiba/wms"


var urlcouches="BV_chiba:deepwatertable"


var deepwatertable = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source:new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: urlgeoserver,
        params:{"LAYERS": urlcouches, "TILED":"true"},
        projection: 'EPSG:32632'
    }),
    title: "deepwatertable"
});
deepwatertable.setVisible(true);


var listcouches= [deepwatertable];
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers:listcouches,
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([0, 0], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:32632'),
    zoom:10,
    projection: 'EPSG:32632'
  })
});
```